# How to make a matrix with specified logic

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix `A=`

```
r_11 r_21 r_31 r_41 r_51 r_61
r_12 r_22 r_32 r_42 r_52 r_62
r_13 r_23 r_33 r_43 r_53 r_63
r_14 r_24 r_34 r_44 r_54 r_64
```

I need to construct a matrix `B` of size `6x4` with the following conditions

1. Collecting any four rows of `B` should give me the combination of only one set, i.e by selecting any three rows i should get either `{r_11,r_12,r_13,r_14}` or `{r_21 r_22 r_23 r_24}` or `{r_31,r_32,r_33,r_34}` or`{r_41,r_42,r_43,r_44}` or`{r_51,r_52,r_53,r_54}` or `{r_61,r_62,r_63,r_64}`
2. No row can contain entries of the type `r_ij and r_ik`. One such arrangement is given below

   `r_11  r_53  r_62 r_44
    r_12  r_21  r_54 r_63
    r_13  r_22  r_31 r_64
    r_14  r_23  r_32 r_41
    r_51  r_24  r_33 r_42
    r_52  r_61  r_34 r_43`

   Can somebody help me to code this, and also suggest some general way to do this efficiently

Comment: It appears that the manipulation is application-specific.  I don't see the relational pattern governing how the individual cells are reoriented from the 6x4 layout to the 4x6 layout.  Additional details would be helpful.

Comment: Seems like a type of [constraint-satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem), like the eight queens or sudokus, although I don't know if it is a well-known one, or if it can be made equivalent to one.